# Auto-refresh Json data in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, charts, highcharts

I've been working this for past 4 days but still can figure out how to solve this issue:

1. The data in the database changes every 5 minutes.
2. I want to display the data in a new chart without refreshing the whole page.

#### CODE:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("test2.php", function(json) {
            Highcharts.setOptions({
                global: {
                    useUTC: false
                }
            });

            $('#container').highcharts({
                renderTo: 'container',
                defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                chart: {
                    type: 'area',
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Transaction Count'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '5 Minutes Count'
                },
                exporting: { 
                    enabled: false 
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories:json,
                    title:{
                        text: 'Time Of The Day',
                        style: {
                            color: '#666666',
                                fontSize: '12px',
                                fontWeight: 'normal'
                            }
                        },
                        tickInterval: 4,
                        type: 'datetime',
                        labels: {
                            style: {
                                fontFamily: 'Tahoma'
                            },
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Number Of Transaction'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            formatter: function () {
                                return this.value;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b>'
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        column: {colorByPoint: true},
                        area: {
                            marker: {
                            enabled: false,
                            symbol: 'circle',
                            radius: 5,
                            states: {
                                hover: {
                                    enabled: true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                colors: [
                    'green',  //Buy
                    '#4572A7' //Paid
                ],
                series: json
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see where you refresh the data. Can you provide more info on your question?

Comment: I used json to fetch the data in database. My problem is the data update every seconds..I want to display the updated data in highchart without reloading the page

Answer (score 5):

You can change the dataset, like this :

```
$('#container').highcharts().series[0].setData([129.2,144.0,...], false);
```

You can redraw, like this :

```
$('#container').highcharts().redraw();
```

So, what you need to do, is create a function that (1) first gets the data from the server, (2) then updates the data and (3) then redraws, like this :

```
var updateChart = function() {
    $.getJSON('test2.json', function(data) {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        $.each(data, function(pos, serie) {
            chart.series[pos].setData(serie, false);
        });
        chart.redraw();
    });
}
```

To repeat this every 5 minutes, you can use `setInterval`, like this :

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON('test2.json', function(data) {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        $.each(data, function(pos, serie) {
            chart.series[pos].setData(serie, false);
        });
        chart.redraw();
    });
}, 300000);
```

Comment: Thanx bro but I can't  understand it since Im a newbie in highchart and not familiar with javascript functions. Very Much appreciated if you can rewrite the whole script..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting your Highchart script in the document.ready function, you can create a funcion getHighchart and put the code about into it. and depend on how many seconds you want the code to  readload as below, but you have to be referencing the jquery js.

```
$(function () {
    setInterval(getHighChart, 30000); //30 seconds onload="getHighChart()" 
});

function getHighChart() {
    //to containe you script for loading the chart
}
```